# Text flowing underneath

Tags: html, css

I'm just thinking about a possible issue I my have when I'm creating a web page.

I can't add the image because I don't have 10 reputation.

The text will continue to flow underneath an image.

I was working with W3C http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float and just added a few more lines.

Is this because the paragraph tag isn't in it's own div?

Comment: show some of your source code

Comment: go to the link provide in my post and then copy in some new lines until the text appears underneath the image

Answer (score 0):

this is the whole purpose of floating elements.
that other content can flow around them.
in your case, there a lot of text , so it floats around the image (the image have a float assigned).

read more about floats [here](http://phrogz.net/css/understandingfloats.html).